# If every cubic metre of space contained roughly 10^41 photons, each with a wavelength of 88 billion light years, would it be possible to detect them

Tags: cosmology

There is a reason to the question but I don't think the stack exchange will allow me to give it. It would be proposing a personal theory, which is not allowed. But we are allowed to ask speculative questions so I think the question should be allowed to stand as it is.

This is, by the way, close to the critical density that all FLRW solutions to Einstein's field equations must have.

Comment: Note that such "photons" would really be associated with spatially uniform electromagnetic fields (on all relevant scales), with strengths $5\times 10^{-5}$ gauss and 1.6 N/C.

Comment: photons do not have wavelengths, they are point elementary particles with energy hν where ν is the frequency of the classical light wave they build up when in large numbers. buildings are made of bricks but a brick is not a building.

Comment: Detecting something that only changes by one part in 88 billion *per year* is going to be challenging, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

If there was that much EM radiation it would drastically alter the expansion of the universe.

Normal matter dilutes in the way you would expect as the universe expands i.e. if the scale factor doubles the density of matter falls by a factor of $2^3$. However radiation density falls as the fourth power of the scale factor i.e. a doubling would reduce the radiation density by $2^4$. This means for the radiation density to be about equal to the critical density now it would have been much, much higher than the critical density in the early universe. Exactly what this would mean for the history of the universe I'm not sure - I would have to do the calculation. Suffice to say that it would be so drastically different from what we observe that we can confidently rule it out.

Comment: These photons would be created as the universe expands, a little bit like dark energy. In fact their mass would be directly proportional to the scale factor. This answer is interesting but I would really like to know if such photons could be detectable.

Answer (score -1):

The plasma frequency of intergalactic plasma (~1 electron per cubic meter) is about 10 Hz, far, far larger than the frequency of your radiation. Your radiation cannot exist: space is a conductor, a "short circuit" to it.

Comment: But I would still like to know whether it would be detectable. Does your answer take into account the enormous wavelength?

Comment: @JohnHobson The enormous wavelength demands a miniscule frequency.

Comment: It seems highly likely to me that these photons are generated, somewhat like the Hawking radiation from a black hole. I already think that 95% of them immediately condense into baryons. I suppose it is quite possible that the remaining 5% are also destroyed. Do you know what they would end up as?